# How can I remove the spacing around an Android Material Slider?

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to arrange my UI and I can't seem to remove the spacing around my slider. It's a basic Material Slider (pictured below). I've tried changing minHeight & minWidth with no luck & I'd prefer not to pad negatively. I assume there must be a way to make the slider's bounds just be around the actual slider image.

[See Slider Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0rKk.png)

Answer (score 1):

The height of the slider is controlled by the dimension `R.dimen.mtrl_slider_widget_height`. You can change the height by specifying in *dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="mtrl_slider_widget_height">30dp</dimen>
```

Or whatever height you would like. There are some other resources loaded in the BaseSlider.java that may be helpful.

```
private void loadResources(@NonNull Resources resources) {
    widgetHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_widget_height);

    minTrackSidePadding = resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_track_side_padding);
    trackSidePadding = minTrackSidePadding;

    defaultThumbRadius = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_thumb_radius);

    trackTop = resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_track_top);

    labelPadding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.mtrl_slider_label_padding);
}
```